# getting started with jensembl

Tags: java, field, bioinformatics

I'm starting a very small project with JEnsembl and I'm not used to trying out new API's. I was wondering why this was running into problems:

```
DBRegistry reg = DBRegistry.createUninitializedRegistryForDataSource(DataSource.ENSEMBLDB);
```

In Eclipse, ENSEMBLDB cannot be resolved to a field. I was wondering how to fix this, since it seems like ENSEMBLDB is the default for the datasource. What should I be writing that is different?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've imported the correct [`DataSource`](http://jensembl.sourceforge.net/apidocs/uk/ac/roslin/ensembl/config/DBConnection.DataSource.html) class and not one of the other ones currently available in Java (e.g. `javax.sql.DataSource`). The [JAR file](http://jensembl.sourceforge.net/download.html) should be on your IDE's classpath.